# How to connect 2 windows using pyqtSignal in PyQt?

Tags: python, windows, pyqt

I create simple application using 2 windows, and i want connect it with button using pyqtsignal, but when i run the application display information "TypeError: pyqtSignal must be bound to a QObject, not 'Form1'":

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import form2
import sys
from functools import partial
from PyQt4.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from lib2to3.fixer_util import String

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Form1(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    Form2Signal = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(319, 147)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.bt_form1 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.bt_form1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 101, 41))
        self.bt_form1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("bt_form1"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 319, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.bt_form1.clicked.connect(self.Form2Signal.emit(String))
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Form_1", None))
        self.bt_form1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FORM_1", None))

class Form2(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    Form1Signal = pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(319, 147)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.bt_form2 = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.bt_form2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 30, 101, 41))
        self.bt_form2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("bt_form2"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 319, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.bt_form2.clicked.connect(self.Form1Signal.emit)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Form_2", None))
        self.bt_form2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "FORM_2", None))

class MainWidget(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.stack = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.stack)
        self.form1 = Form1(self)
        self.form2 = Form2(self)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.form1)
        self.stack.addWidget(self.form2)
        self.form1.Form2Signal.connect(partial(self.stack.setCurrentWidget,self.form2))
        self.form2.Form1Signal.connect(partial(self.stack.setCurrentWidget,self.form1))
        self.stack.setCurrentWidget(self.form1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWidget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Lines like this `self.bt_form1.clicked.connect(self.Form2Signal.emit(String))` don't make any sense. What are you attempting to do with this line of code? It also might be a good idea to refresh your understanding of signals and slots by reading a tutorial, like this: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/ That way you can probably explain what you are trying to do a bit better and we'll be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `super(Form1, self).__init__()` in `__init__` method of `Form1` class. Do the same for `Form2`

Comment: While you are correct that this line is missing, It does not fix the error posted. Did you actually run the code?

Comment: Yes I did, and it fixes error `TypeError: pyqtSignal must be bound to a QObject, not 'Form1'` giving next error witch is about wrong signal arguments and that is material for a new question.

Comment: I've run it, but when run directly display form 2 , and there is an error "QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWidget "", which already has a layout", are you know about the problem ?

Comment: @user3292107 If Aleksandar's answer fixes the stated problem, you should accept answer, and post new question, not extend question to cover more errors.

Comment: No problem. About that layout: some widgets, like your `MainWidget(QtGui.QMainWindow)` already have layout, so solution might be to set empty widget with your custom layout as `centralWidget` of your MainWidget. Or take a look at `QWidget::layout()` and `QWidget::setLayout` here [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#layout) , it says "You must first delete the existing layout manager (returned by layout()) before you can call setLayout() with the new layout."