# Connections in Pyqt forms

Tags: pyqt, qt-designer

I have been newly working on developing a desktop application and i am stuck with this topic. I have two forms and I want to connect Buttons/widgets of one form to Buttons/widgets of another. Is it even possible to do that? I know it can be done in the same form but if someone knows about it, please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add what you *tried* up until now? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Basically what exactly I want is if I give x,y,z variables in a lineEdit widget in form1 then those variable should appear in a form of a table in form2. Can you help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22903322/how-to-connect-2-windows-using-pyqtsignal-in-pyqt